# How to add a where clause in a MySQL Insert statement?

Tags: mysql, insert, where-clause

This doesn't work:

```
INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES ("Jack","123") WHERE id='1';
```

Any ideas how to narrow insertion to a particular row by id?

Comment: Downvoted. As it stands, either the title is wrong, or the accepted answer. Anyway, Google leads me here for *insert*, but the accepted answer is about *update*.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

In an insert statement you wouldn't have an existing row to do a where claues on?  You are inserting a new row, did you mean to do an update statment?

```
update users set username='JACK' and password='123' WHERE id='1';
```

Comment: "you wouldn't have an existing row to do a where claues on?" Perfect answer.

Comment: I want to do a where clause on the rest of the table. E.g `insert ... where count(..) < 10`.

Answer (score 15):

A conditional insert for use typically in a MySQL script would be:

```
insert into t1(col1,col2,col3,...)
select val1,val2,val3,...
  from dual
 where [conditional predicate];
```

You need to use dummy table dual.

In this example, only the second insert-statement will actually insert data into the table:

```
create table t1(col1 int);
insert into t1(col1) select 1 from dual where 1=0;
insert into t1(col1) select 2 from dual where 1=1;
select * from t1;
+------+
| col1 |
+------+
|    2 |
+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 6):

To add a WHERE clause inside an INSERT statement simply;

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1,column2,column3)
SELECT column1, column2, column3 FROM  table_name
WHERE column1 = 'some_value'
```

Comment: er, could you add some information as to what is going on here? Why does the insert need a WHERE?

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for [UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html) and not insert?

```
UPDATE `users`
SET `username` = 'Jack', `password` = '123'
WHERE `id` = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Update users
Set username = 'Jack', password='123'
Where ID = '1'
```

Or if you're actually trying to insert:

```
Insert Into users (id, username, password) VALUES ('1', 'Jack','123');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
INSERT INTO users (id,username, password) 
VALUES ('1','Jack','123')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE username='Jack',password='123'
```

This will work only if the `id` field is unique/pk (not composite PK though)
Also, this will insert if no `id` of value 1 is found and update otherwise the record with `id` 1 if it does exists.

Answer (score 2):

For Empty row how we can insert values on where clause

Try this

```
UPDATE table_name SET username="",password="" WHERE id =""
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE users SET username='&username', password='&password' where id='&id'
```

This query will ask you to enter the username,password and id dynamically

Comment: This query will ask you to enter the username,password and id dynamically