# SQL INSERT statement Error - Error at Where clause

Tags: mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to add a where clause in a MySQL Insert statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349993/how-to-add-a-where-clause-in-a-mysql-insert-statement)

I am writing a SQL INSERT STATEMENT with  WHERE clause.

```
 INSERT INTO House ( ID ,ADDRESS ) VALUES ('12','LONDON') WHERE OWNER='1';
```

Error i get :

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE OWNER='1'' at line 1
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349993/how-to-add-a-where-clause-in-a-mysql-insert-statement same question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`WHERE` is used in `UPDATE query`. Use UPDATE for your query if got where clause.

Comment: I think what i need is an `UPDATE` query. Thanks

Comment: `UPDATE House Set ID='12',values='LONDON' WHERE OWNER='1';`

Answer (score 4):

You can't use `WHERE` clause with `INSERT` Query..

If you want update the record already if the record exist

```
INSERT INTO House ( OWNER, ID ,ADDRESS ) VALUES ('1', '12','LONDON') 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ID = '12', ADDRESS = 'LONDON'
```

The '**ON DUPLICATE KEY**' statement only works on **PRIMARY** KEY and **UNIQUE** columns

check this [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) for more info

Answer (score 1):

INSERT INTO doesn't have a WHERE clause. Remove it.

Answer (score 1):

You can onlu use the `WHERE` clause if you are selecting from a table, or updateing a table.

So you wouls typically have something like

```
INSERT INTO Table (Columns...) SELECT Columns... FROM SomeOtherTable WHERE Condition
```

In your case you need to use

```
INSERT INTO House ( ID ,ADDRESS ) VALUES ('12','LONDON')
```

Answer (score 1):

WHERE clause doesnot work with INSERT INTO statement. You can use the clause with a SELECT statement

The correct code for you will be as:

INSERT INTO House(ID,ADDRESS) values(12,'LONDON');