# how to insert data in max id by using sql query

Tags: php, mysql

I want to get the maximum id of row data. In my table first column is id then firstname. this is the sql command I used to get the max(id) of row data and insert firstname in max(id) row. but it is not working

---

```
<?PHP  $maxid=mysql_query("insert into test(firstname) values ('$sym') where id =max('id') ;?>
```

Comment: why don't you use update query?

Comment: you need update not insert

Comment: sir i have id's in ID column..and i want to insert firstname in max(id) row

Comment: possibly duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349993/how-to-add-a-where-clause-in-a-mysql-insert-statement

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your requirement in this way.

```
UPDATE test
   SET  firstname = '$sym'
 ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: i am not getting max(id)

Comment: mysql_query("update disorder_symptom set sym_id='$sym' WHERE 'id' = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM disorder_symptom);");

Comment: i am getting error...........#1093 - You can't specify target table 'test' for update in FROM clause

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE yourtable
   SET  firstname = '$sym'
 WHERE id in (SELECT max(id) from yourtable)
```